# Display object ids in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to alert my objects id's. When i specify `objects[0] or objects[1]` everything works and it displays the id, what should i write to do it automatically ?

```
$scope.deleteInv = function () {
    var garums = $scope.info.objects[1].id;
    alert(garums);
};
```

Comment: You want to loop them -- if you want to display in the view loop with `ng-repeat` on an element, else use `for` loop or `angular.forEach`

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with angular.

here:

    $scope.deleteInv = function() {
        var garums = $scope.info.objects;
        for (var i = 0; i <= garums.length; ++i) {
            alert(garums[i].id);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out, if someone needs

Inventory = is my factory

```
$scope.deleteInv = function(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.info.objects.length; i++){
        if($scope.info.objects[i].id == id){
            Inventory.drop({id: id});
            break;
        } 
    }
};
```